# ComboBox with Checkboxes closes on Checkbox Click

Tags: wpf, combobox, checkbox, popup

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503022/wpf-combobox-with-checkbox-selecteditem) same problem, but the solution presented isn't working, nor is any other I've found.  I want to create a `ComboBox` with `CheckBox`es as part of the `ItemTemplate`.  This has been accomplished.  But the problem arises when the user clicks a `CheckBox`:  the `PopUp` closes.  I need it to stay open.

I tried handling the `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` event and the `CheckBox.Click` event, but I can't get it.  From tracing through the code, it appears that the SelectionChanged event doesn't fire at all when the user clicks the `CheckBox`, which is matches the behavior of the control as nothing appears in the `TextBox` portion.

This is not for multiple selection, but rather to have the `CheckBox` bind to a property in the data context.

Here is some sample code

```
<Toolbar VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyType">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Clicked"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <local:MyType Title="item 1"/>
        <local:MyType Title="item 2"/>
        <local:MyType Title="item 3"/>
        <local:MyType Title="item 4"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Toolbar>

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do some stuff
}

private void CheckBox_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // change a property on the data context if not data bound

    // Tried this, but Popup just closes then reopens
    comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    // This seems to have no effect
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

I noticed that there is a difference of behavior when the `ComboBox` is placed in a `Toolbar`.  When not in the `Toolbar`, it behaves as expected: the `CheckBox` changes state without closing the `Popup`.  But in the `ToolBar`, the `Popup` closes on the first click, regardless of where the click is.  Try the new code, please.  I really need this in a toolbar.

**EDIT 2:**

For posterity and anyone searching for it, [MS suggested](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/859bae90-2f92-42dc-af79-46b9193f0dd2) setting the Focusable property of the CheckBox in the DataTemplate to false.  This achieves the desired effect.

Comment: You should not have CheckBoxes in a ComboBox in the first place.

Comment: I agree with @H.B. a combobox shouldn't be multi-selectable.  The reason is that there is then no standard way to close the combobox i.e. you have to find a different place to click to close it.  Much better to have an expandable element of some sort to contain a simple listbox.

Comment: I've copied your solution to the blank wpf project, but I can't reproduce your problem: the popup remains open when I click checkboxes. It becames closed only if I click somewhere outside the combobox.

Comment: @mydogisbox:  As I stated this is not for multiple selection.  This is for editing properties of the source objects.  The ComboBox is a common interface element for users.  This type of control is used in AutoCAD for basic editing of layers.

Comment: @vortex, I will try it in a new solution.  Maybe something else in my project is causing the problem.

Comment: @gregsdennis: Could you just use a different non-ComboBox control?  Then, define a `Popup` containing a `ListBox`.  Define a `ListBox.ItemTemplate` with a `CheckBox`.

Comment: @jberger, It sounds like you're wanting me to reinvent the `ComboBox`.  I thought about doing that, but I figured there should be a better solution.

Comment: @gregsdennis: There could very well be a simple, yet obscure boolean flag which is all that is needed.  However, if .NET does not have an implemented solution, I'm merely pointing out a possibility...

Comment: Focusable="False" really makes the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `Toolbar` control affects the `ComboBox` control in some way. And strangely, the `ComboBox` isn't closed when you put the cursor inside the `TextBox`, but works wrong with the `CheckBox`.

The quickest way to solve this issue is to change focus manually when a user clicks the `CheckBox`.
I use the following sequence of steps:

1) Handle the `GotFocus` event for every control in the application

2) Leave only events of the `CheckBox` control

3) Check whether the `CheckBox` is inside the current `ComboBox`

4) If yes, return focus to the `ComboBox`

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //...

        comboBox.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.GotFocusEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)OnGotFocus);
    }

    private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is CheckBox)
        {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            var comboBoxItem = GetParentElement<ComboBoxItem>(e.OriginalSource);

            if (comboBoxItem != null && comboBox.Items.OfType<object>().Select(comboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem).Contains(comboBoxItem))
                comboBox.Focus();
        }
    }

    private T GetParentElement<T>(object element) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var current = element as DependencyObject;

        while (current != null && !(current is T))
        {
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }

        return current as T;
    }
```

It is a quite messy solution, but anyway it works.

Comment: wow.  Thanks.  That _is_ messy.  But I guess you have to do what's necessary to get it to work.  I've started a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214948/wpf-combobox-in-toolbar-behaves-differently) to see if anyone can determine why it behaves differently.  You may like to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the Check ComboBox control, which is part of the WPF extended toolkit. You can find it here: [Check ComboBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckComboBox&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: The page says that this control is still under development.  Also, that control is for multiple selection, not editing properties of the underlying data object.  Thank you, though.