# Combobox in toolbar behaves differently

Tags: wpf, combobox, checkbox, toolbar

Starting a new question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126570/combobox-with-checkboxes-closes-on-checkbox-click) thread, Can anyone answer why a `ComboBox` with `CheckBox`es would behave differently inside and outside of a toolbar?

Summary from linked question:

I noticed that there is a difference of behavior when the ComboBox is placed in a Toolbar. When not in the Toolbar, it behaves as expected: the CheckBox changes state without closing the Popup. But in the ToolBar, the Popup closes on the first click, regardless of where the click is. Try the new code, please. I really need this in a toolbar.

Comment: What do you mean by differently ?

Comment: What are the differents behaviors ?

Comment: @AharonMuallem, if you read the EDIT portion of the linked question, it will describe the difference for you.

Comment: @jberger, Very well.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/859bae90-2f92-42dc-af79-46b9193f0dd2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to thank jberger for suggesting I go to MS.

As [suggested by MS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/859bae90-2f92-42dc-af79-46b9193f0dd2), the solution is to set the `CheckBox.Focusable` property to `False` in the template.

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="MyDataClass">
        <CheckBox Focusable="False" ... />
        <TextBlock ... />
    </DataTemplate>
```

This provides the desired behavior when the `ComboBox` is either in a `ToolBar` or just floating in some `Panel`.

Comment: Still has the same problem when Combobox is inside a Toolbar.